# Using PHP variables in HTML when the HTML is in a PHP variable

Tags: html, variables, php

I've got a .php script. In a variable I have a added html, but in that html I want to get text from another variable, how do I do this?

This is the variable with html:

```
$ai_boc   = '
<html>
<head>
  <title>Notes by Douno</title>
</head>

<body>
<div align="center">
<div style="width:600px; height:auto; border-radius:10px; background-color:#F7F1B8; background-repeat: auto; font-family:Georgia;  color:#513414;">

    <div style="height:100px; padding-top:20px; padding-left:20px; text-align:left;">
    <p style="margin-bottom:0px; font-weight:bold; font-size:xx-large;">$ai_su</p>
    <p style="margin-top:5px; font-size:x-small; font-weight:bold;">$ai_da</p>
    </div>
        <div style="height:1px; background-image: url(http://dl.dropbox.com/u/99775621/divider.jpg); display:block; position:relative;">
        </div>
    <div style="position:relative; overflow:hidden;">

        <div style="height:auto; width:375; padding-left:20px; text-align:left; position:relative; float:left;">
            <div style="width:375px;"> <p style="font-size:x-small; font-weight:bold;"><?php echo $ai_bo?></p>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div style="height:auto; width:160px; padding-left:20px; padding-right:20px; text-align:left; position:relative; float:left;">
        <p style="font-size:x-small; font-weight:bold; vertical-align:bottom;">If this email is considered spam, please contact us.</br></br>This email was send via Notes. An Android app developed by Douno.</p>
        <a href="https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=appinventor.ai_L_Bogaerts_95.Notes">
        <img alt="Get it on Google Play"
        src="https://developer.android.com/images/brand/en_generic_rgb_wo_45.png" />
        </a>

        </div>

    </div>
        <div style="height:1px; background-image: url(http://dl.dropbox.com/u/99775621/divider.jpg); display:block; position:relative;">
        </div>
    <div style="height:100px; width:600px; display:inline-block; position:relative;">

    </div>      






</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
';
```

I coudn't find any working explanation, so I hope someone here can help me further. The html is not finished... Still some changes I'm gonna make.

Comment: I am sure your code works, but please do not do this. Take some time to learn MVC, Smarty or other paradigms to create decent PHP sites. Stuff like this gives PHP its bad name.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use either string concatenation, or variable expansion:

```
 $html = '<html>'.$somevar.'</html>';      // concatenation
 $html = "<html>$somevar</html>";           // expansion, only works with double quotes (")
```

But **much** better is to use a [decent template system](http://www.smarty.net/) to separate HTML and PHP altogether.

Answer (score 2):

You can use something like this:

```
$test = 'test';
$html = '<h1>' . $test . '</h1>';
```

or

```
$test = 'test';
echo "Hello {$test}";
```

another way (available only in PHP 5.3+):

```
    $test = 'test';
    $html = <<<EOT 
Hello $test
EOT;
```

Answer (score 1):

Use HEREDOC ..
You can have HTML and PHP variables inside Heredoc like you would generally do it.

```
$ai_boc   = <<< EOT
<html>
<head>
  <title>Notes by Douno</title>
</head>

<body>
<div align="center">
<div style="width:600px; height:auto; border-radius:10px; background-color:#F7F1B8; background-repeat: auto; font-family:Georgia;  color:#513414;">

    <div style="height:100px; padding-top:20px; padding-left:20px; text-align:left;">
    <p style="margin-bottom:0px; font-weight:bold; font-size:xx-large;">$ai_su</p>
    <p style="margin-top:5px; font-size:x-small; font-weight:bold;">$ai_da</p>
    </div>
        <div style="height:1px; background-image: url(http://dl.dropbox.com/u/99775621/divider.jpg); display:block; position:relative;">
        </div>
    <div style="position:relative; overflow:hidden;">

        <div style="height:auto; width:375; padding-left:20px; text-align:left; position:relative; float:left;">
            <div style="width:375px;"> <p style="font-size:x-small; font-weight:bold;"><?php echo $ai_bo?></p>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div style="height:auto; width:160px; padding-left:20px; padding-right:20px; text-align:left; position:relative; float:left;">
        <p style="font-size:x-small; font-weight:bold; vertical-align:bottom;">If this email is considered spam, please contact us.</br></br>This email was send via Notes. An Android app developed by Douno.</p>
        <a href="https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=appinventor.ai_L_Bogaerts_95.Notes">
        <img alt="Get it on Google Play"
        src="https://developer.android.com/images/brand/en_generic_rgb_wo_45.png" />
        </a>

        </div>

    </div>
        <div style="height:1px; background-image: url(http://dl.dropbox.com/u/99775621/divider.jpg); display:block; position:relative;">
        </div>
    <div style="height:100px; width:600px; display:inline-block; position:relative;">

    </div>      






</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
EOT;
```

Answer (score 0):

try to add this to your code -

```
$ai_boc .= $other_var;
```

Answer (score 0):

Your main quotes should be double quotes, the you can say

```
$ai_boc="<html ... {$variable} ... more html";
```

Answer (score 0):

There are a few options.

PHP understands quotes in different ways (read this, should clarify your doubt: http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php)

Lastly, this is how it should work:

```
$replacement = "This is a string I want to insert into another one";
$bigger_text = "This is a bigger text. {$replacement} And the former variable has just been inserted here";
```

This happens because PHP "parses" double quotes and interpolates variables when needed.

It's also a good practice to brace your interpolated strings with braces {} for clarity's sake and also allowing you to interpolate things like this:

```
$interpolated = "Hello {$user[0]['name']}.";
```

Answer (score 0):

When you have a long html string you can use `ob_start()`and `ob_get_clean()` :

```
<?php
ob_start();

$title = "My website";

?><html>
    <head>
        <title><?=$title?></title>
    </head>
    <body>
        ...
    </body>
</html><?php

$ai_boc = ob_get_clean();
```

Answer (score 0):

If you must embed large block of HTML in your PHP code, then the HEREDOC syntax described in @Kalpesh Mehta's answer is the way to do it.

However, the best answer here is to use a proper templating mechanism - even it's just a basic string-replace of a predefined marker. Then you can split your HTML out to a separate file, which will make it much easier to work with than having it embedded in a PHP string.

So `template.html` contains your code, with markers like `{marker}` where you want the variables.

Then your PHP code can just look like this:

```
$ai_boc = file_get_contents('template.html');
$ai_boc = str_replace('{marker}', $my_variable, $ai_boc);
print $ai_boc;
```

Answer (score -1):

**Exapmle:**

$var="Test";

```
$html="<html> $var </html>";
```

**OR**

```
$html="<html>". $var." </html>";
```